# Is the text of the "Hamburg ceasefire agreement" public?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, syria, reference-request, jordan

I read [that](https://www.middleeasteye.net/news/jordan-syria-camp-food-convoy-violence-border):

> In 2017, the US, Israel, Russia and Jordan reached a four-part agreement over southern Syria, with Moscow essentially committing to keeping Iran-backed groups away from the border. But the invasion of Ukraine has stoked fears that Russia's focus has shifted and will allow Iran's influence to expand there [...]

Elsewhere, I read this agreement is also [called](https://www.dohainstitute.org/en/PoliticalStudies/Pages/The_USRussian_Agreement_on_Syria_Aims_and_Implications_of_the_Hamburg_Ceasefire.aspx) the  "Hamburg [Ceasefire] Agreement" (because it was agreed on the sides of the G20 summit in that city). But I can't seem to find its text. Is it public?

Comment: Strangely, I found [one](https://www.peaceagreements.org/viewmasterdocument/2093) involving Iran and Turkey, plus the Russian Federation, so I'm guessing it's a different one, or that's why it's a "four part" thing?

Comment: according to [this news item in Hebrew](https://www.maariv.co.il/news/world/Article-608344) Israel was not a party to the agreement. moreover, the article from 2017 quotes an Israeli member of cabinet saying although russia was committed to keep iranian forces away from the border, the agreement does not answer all of Israel's concerns

Comment: by the way, Hamburg was the location of G20 summit in July 2017, where the issue was discussed between president Trump and Putin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the text of the agreement has not been made public.

Four days after the agreement, reporters for [Foreign Policy](https://foreignpolicy.com/2017/07/11/exclusive-trump-putin-ceasefire-agreement-focuses-on-iranian-backed-fighters-middle-east/) wrote:

> A confidential U.S.-Russian cease-fire agreement for southwestern Syria that went into effect Sunday [9 July 2017] calls for barring Iranian-backed foreign fighters from a strategic stretch of Syrian territory near the borders of Israel and Jordan, according to three diplomatic sources.
>
> President Donald Trump hailed it as an important agreement that would serve to save lives. But few details of the accord have been made public.
>
> U.S. Defense Department officials — who would have responsibility for monitoring the agreement — appeared to be in the dark about the pact’s fine print.

Other sources mention references to elements of the agreement, but no references or links to the actual text.