Why isn't Syria treating Israel's attack in Damascus as an open act of war?
Israel allegedly attacked an Iranian consulate building in Damascus recently.
Launching airstrikes on another country's territory without their permission is presumably an unambiguous act of war. Why isn't Syria reacting as though they've just been attacked (similar to e.g. how the US reacted after Pearl Harbor)?

Who is to say that Syria and Israel aren't already at war? Why is this different from past Israeli strikes on Syria?

@ohwilleke if they're already at war, it's not declared.

This isn't at all clear from the answer I've seen so far. Also, a declaration of war can be one sided.

@ohwilleke does Israel or Syria currently consider themselves at war with the other party? If so, I'll consider that an answer.

Arguing about declarations of war isn't all that relevant when almost no actual formal states of war get declared by anyone anymore these days.

How would you expect Syria to react? Pear Harbor isn't really an accurate comparison, especially when you don't refer to which action the US took after Pearl Harbor (do you expect Syria to declare war on Israel's allies, as the US did on Germany? Maybe Syria should send fleets of bombers to bomb the US? Or send some aircraft carriers against Israel?)

@StuartF: it's actually Germany which solved the potential conundrum and declared war on the US first. (OTOH a poll just before that had 90% support for the US declaring war on Germany anyway--it was widely [and effectively] rumoured that Germany had pulled the strings on Pearl Harbor). See the last para of "background" here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_declaration_of_war_against_the_United_States

@StuartF: and technically speaking the US and Israel aren't allies in that strict sense of having a mutual defense treaty, even if US politicians often call Israel their best ally in the middle east etc. Although since '73 everyone expects the US to bail out Israel, in extremis, although that's hardly needed since Israel has [at least] 100 nukes or so.

Israel and Syria are in state of war. The war is declared long ago. Later, a cease-fire was signed. Syria routinely complains to the UN committee on the seasefire violations by Israel (and so does Israel). There is an UN peacekeeping forces on the border between the two countries. Israel seemingly justifies the strikes by saying they are targeting Iranian personnel.

It would technically be impossible for Syria to declare war on Israel, as most Arab countries do not even acknowledge the existence of Israel as a state. Meanwhile, Israel claims all its acts as self-defense which do not necessitate a declaration of war.

@xuq01 War doesn't necessitate a declaration of war -- to start with.

@Gábor That is exactly my point - most wars are not declared.

@xuq01: well, if the Syrian gov't were able to sign a ceasefire with Israel (and in fact they had several, one for the common border in '74 and later another for Lebanon after clashes there), a formal declaration of war doesn't seem impossible either, although just a notice that the ceasefire is cancelled would probably suffice. See also how the US-Taliban accord was phrased: US agreed to do such and such, but insisted in the wording that that does not imply a recognition of the Taliban.

@xuq01: similarly, North and South Korea don't recognize each other, but have signed a ceasefire and even some later agreements. At one point NK threatened to formally cancel the ceasefire. More recently SK cancelled [pars of?] one of the additional agreements, and NK apparently responded by cancelling all of it.

It is not the first time that Israel strikes Syria. Moreover, Israel and Syria have been already in war with each other since 1948. And in every active war fought since then, Syria was badly beaten, and even lost some territory.
To expand on the previous paragraph: since 1948, Syria has never officially recognized Israel's existence (although engaged in peace negotiations in the 1990s and 2000s), and was among the Arab states that interfered in the Israeli-Palestinian conflict after Israel's declaration of independence in 1948. Since then, most of the time, the relationships between the two states have been governed by various ceasefire agreements, although on several occasions, active war was resumed - notably in 1967 (Six Day War) and 1973 (Yom Kippour/Autumn War). In 1967, Israel occupied the Golan Heights, which it now considers its own territory (expanding the citizenship rights to all the inhabitants of this region.)
The Israeli military activity in Syria has been intensified since the beginning of the Syrian civil war, but it existed before as well. The major scenarios include:

Retaliation against rockets/shells/shooting into the Israeli-controlled territory. Since it is rarely possible to say whether these are accidental or intended to test Israeli defenses, Israel practices tit-for-tat response.
Targeting Iranian shipments to Hezbollah. Hezbollah is a Lebanese militia created and trained by Iran during the occupation of Lebanon by Israel and Syria. It is especially known for killing 241 American marines and 58 French military-men in 1983 Beirut Barracks bombing, 1992 Buenos Aires Israeli Embassy bombing, and triggering 2006 Israel-Lebanon war. Hezbollah is currently fighting a war with Israel, which prompted an evacuation of the population in northern Israel and regular Israeli threats to invade Lebanon in response (perhaps, after the end of the active war in Gaza.) As Hezbollah is being supplied by Iran, Israel has been over years carrying strikes against these arms shipments, to prevent advanced arms from reaching Lebanon and preserve its military edge (however, Hezbollah does have many systems posing a serious threat, notably drones and scud missiles.)
Iranian military personnel. Israel has been engaged in a cold war and a proxy war with Iran (Hezbollah, Hamas, and Houthis are all Iranian proxies.) Thus, some of the Israeli strikes are intended for targeted assassinations of Iranian officials.
Strikes against Syrian assets. Bombing of Syrian nuclear reactor in 2007 was specifically aimed at Syria itself. In diplomatic terms, the Syrian reaction on this occasion was the strongest, as beyond the usual public denunciations, Syria did lodge a complaint with the UN:


In a letter to the Secretary-General of the United Nations, Ban Ki-moon, Syria called the incursion a "breach of airspace of the Syrian Arab Republic" and said "it is not the first time Israel has violated" Syrian airspace. Syria also accused the international community of ignoring Israeli actions. A UN spokesperson said Syria had not requested a meeting of the UN Security Council and France, at the time the president of the Security Council, said it had received no letter from Syria.

See also: 2023 Israel strikes in Syria.

Maybe they even make a distinction between striking Syria and striking on Syrian territory. It seems like Israel targeted Iran not Syria and Syria simply wants to keep itself out of it?

Power ratio Syria-Israel 2024 ≠ power ratio USA-Japan 1941.  Plus, Assad is in an even worse shape now than he was before the Syrian Civil War - a solid-enough trouncing might cause the population to rebel once again.  Yes, an external war could solidify his rule instead, but why would he wager on that?

Assad's government is in a weaker position now than he was in 2007, when an Israeli airstrike was more clearly targeted at a Syrian facility (alleged to be involved in a nuclear program).
In the meantime, there was a huge civil war in Syria. Assad had to accept Iranian help to stay on top. How much he's really fond of that (continued) presence in the aftermath is hard to say.
Russia also helped Assad in order to keep their bases in Syria etc. (And even that way, Assad still didn't regain control over all the territory thus far.) But Russia does not like Iran's presence there much, as it's essentially a competing sphere of influence. So Russia doesn't help Syria against Israeli strikes that target Iranian forces.
Syria did shoot back at some of the larger Israeli air incursions, at least some years ago. With relatively poor results, overall. In one instance, they reportedly lost a bunch of their SAM batteries (May 2018). In another, they shot down a Russian aircraft (September 2018). True, they also shot down an Israeli one (February 2018), which AFAICT was their only success in all those years. And back then the aircraft (opnely) mentioned on the Israeli side were of the older generation, F-16s etc. Now it's F-35s. Syria is broken financially and their main export is captagon, it seems. Russia isn't helping much in those regards either. So the balance of military (and economic) power is probably not starting to shift in Syria's favor anytime soon. Yeah, Russia claims to have given Assad 'free' S-300PMs in Oct 2018, but thus far those have made no difference.
So, Assad probably judged that verbal protests is as far as he can hope to retaliate, this time.
It's Iran who appears to be acting as the more aggrieved party here (as they reportedly lost 2 brigadier generals in that strike). But even they probably can't do all that much about it. (In the past few years, Iran did lob missiles directly from its territory at an alleged 'Mossad centre' in Iraqi Kurdish territory, more than once.) Iran has been blaming on Israel deaths of Iranian generals in Syria since at least 2013. The list is pretty long by now. And hardly the only type of confrontation in this 'shadow war' or "war between the wars", which has ranged farther with naval events, violent deaths of Iranian nuclear scientists back home etc. And yeah, Iran is mostly fighting back through its proxies: Hezbollah and the whole Axis of Resistance etc. Which of course are also targeted by Israel and (some of which) even by the US directly because the latter also attacked US forces (in Iraq and Syria). OTOH, if we go by statements, Iran definitely plans to retaliate here:

Khamenei has said Iran’s “brave men” will punish Israel, one of his advisers has warned that Israeli embassies “are no longer safe”, and two officials recently told the New York Times they will retaliate directly against Israel, to restore deterrence.


Somewhat aside on declarations of war. AFAICT Syria never declared war on Israel. Not in '48, not in '73 etc. (Presumably because they don't recognize Israel as a country.) So, if  they do somehow decide to [counter-]attack (which like I said is extremely implausible in the current circumstances), they're not likely to declare war first.
According to Wikipedia, Syria had a signed ceasefire with Israel after the '67 war (on June 11), but that of course did not mean much in '73. The reason why the '74 ceasefire mostly holds is almost certainly that Syria's gov't doesn't feel they can win if they fight back more vigorously. And even the latter ceasefire didn't apply e.g. in Lebanon in '82 between the Syrian troops there and the IDF.
Nobody in the region seems to bother to declare that/when they're officially breaking a ceasefire.
Some Israeli leaders speak of the current strikes on Iranian positions in Syria (since 2013 or so) as a 'war between the wars' ("MABAM (Milchama bin HaMilchamot) is the Hebrew acronym for “War between the wars”), or somewhat more officially translated as the "campaign between the wars". Which in some ways resembles the 'war of attrition' that happened between the wars of '67 and '73, despite official ceasefire. (While Wikipedia says the latter ended in 1970 [with another--hah--ceasefire with Egypt, the IDF considers the PLO incursions that continued from the north were a continuation of this.)
E.g. there's 2018 IDF Strategy that says (p. 3):

The document specifies that “the activity of the campaign between wars
is ongoing, occurring throughout the combat arena…in all dimensions of
combat and in a variety of offensive tools – kinetic, legal, diplomatic, cognitive,
technological, electronic, network environments, cooperation, and military
diplomacy. The mode of operation in the campaign between wars is offensive
and proactive, under the threshold of war.”

So, the IDF doesn't see itself as quite at war with Iran but conducting, ahem, (kinetic) "military diplomacy". (At least the last time they updated a formal document in this respect.) And yeah, the term "kinetic diplomacy" has also been coined/used by some, with this def: "In kinetic diplomacy, a state uses primarily military resources to coerce by violence, in order to avoid a costly escalation."
Although not part of that official strategy document, General Nitzan Alon explains the difference as:

most of the IDF’s order of battle is not involved in the campaign
between wars. First, certain groups in the Air Force, the Military Intelligence branch, and the General Staff are engaged in the campaign between wars, along with very specific niches in the Navy and the ground forces.

So, essentially, that sounds a lot like a limited war in other terminology.
The aforelinked INSS study also has this interesting bit:

About half of the airstrikes in Syria in 2022 were not
carried out against weapons transfers or pro-Iranian forces, but were aimed
at Syrian regime targets. Fifty-two percent of the regime targets that were
attacked were Syrian military targets, and 29 percent of the attacks were
aimed against Syrian national infrastructure, airports, and seaports. Unlike
attacks in previous years, which were aimed at a warehouse or a specific
target connected to the shipment of weapons, the four airstrikes carried out
in 2022 on the international airports in Damascus and Aleppo led to their
temporary shutdown.

However, no official IDF document seems to talk about this.

Yeah Russia also called some of these Israeli attacks 'unacceptable' but that's that.

And if you want some kind of ref for the opening paras https://www.cairn-int.info/article.php?ID_ARTICLE=E_COME_113_0177#pa18

This answer contains lots of unverifiable opinions. For example, "But Russia does not like Iran's presence there much, as it's essentially a competing sphere of influence.". Sounds reasonable, but how do we know that is the case?

@BenCohen: see my comment right above yours for one source summarizing the affair. The rubbing of shoulders between Russia and Israel against Iran was a bit more obvious in 2018, when Avigdor Lieberman was praising Putin and launched an offensive after a return trip of Bibi from Moscow. https://www.ft.com/content/ec5e2090-a7bd-11e8-926a-7342fe5e173f etc. Yeah, it's more complicated these days with Shaheds-cum-Gerans, but the Iran-Russia cooperation was ultimately more limited thus that what Russia got from North Korea.

@BenCohen: and related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/86404/is-it-true-that-netanyahu-did-not-make-any-negative-statements-about-the-russi

@BenCohen: almost forgot about https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78939/is-the-text-of-the-hamburg-ceasefire-agreement-public

Because it has not anything to win, and lots of things to lose.
So Syria declares war on Israel... and then what? They may attack Israel and cause some casualties, but the price to pay would be heavy.
Syria's military is weaker than Israel. It could cause losses for Israel, but Syria would be ok there losing side.
Worse yet, they would give an excuse for direct intervention of the USA, which to begin with is not friendly towards the current Syrian regime.
And if Syria suffers a crushing defeat, then Israel and the USA could be the least of Assad's troubles. As explained in other answers, Syria has been torn by a civil war and the regime is mostly maintained by the army, and Russian support. Wipe the army and then opposition groups (some of which were supported by the USA) could be a worse threat.

Yeah, since Israel declared 'regime change' (albeit not in those words) a goal of their present campaign in Gaza, they could even do the same in Syria, and even co-opt some of the opposition there. In fact, they kinda did that during the Lebanon civil war in the 80's. So, Assad can't afford to annoy Israel much.

In short, the Syrian government is not in a position to fight Israel.
Syria is partially occupied by:

Kurdistan forces - who are there as part of a regional independence movement
Turks - who are there nominally to keep the Kurdish movement in check
remnants of Al Qaeda - under whatever name they call themselves in a given year - they were a significant part of the anti-Assad coalition under the HTS label, but appear largely eliminated by now
a mix of foreign fighters and actual Syrians - under the flag of the Free Syrian Army, whose goal is to overthrow Assad's government, and who were the other significant working part of the anti-Assad coalition
ISIL - under the nominal goal of setting up an international Islamic fundamentalist state, but in practice they just seem to pop up opportunistically to cause trouble
actual US forces with proper flag and insignia - who invited themselves in under the guise of fighting terrorism, after the circa-2013 regime change was nixed by protesting US service members. In recent years seen guarding the Syrian government's oil producing regions to the East, which worked out in practice with the oil being trucked away in broad daylight by parties unknown. More recently hunkered down in their bases dodging potshots from irate Arabs of the region.
Russian forces, present in bases by treaty, and actually invited and welcomed unlike the other members of this list. They helped beat back AQ/HTS and FSA and helped the Syrian government regain control of much of the West, but can't do anything about the US presence in particular. The close coexistence with US forces is tense.
Iraqi-factional and Iranian assistance against the various invaders also appears accepted by the Syrian government.

Amid the chaos from this mix of parties, Israel has been routinely bombing Syria, usually with standoff missile strikes. It is typically (as now) justified under the guise of retaliation for events taking place elsewhere which Israel attributes to Iran. In practice, it seems that Syria is simply an opportunity for Israel to reach what they believe are Iranian personnel, and in this case really were - which would have been considerably harder in Iran itself.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Fundamentally, it's in Syria's interest to basically ignore what Israel is doing even though they are clearly acts of war.  Look at the two scenarios:

Syria ignores it.  Israel hits Iranian targets, basically ignores Syrian military.  Syria has some bombs go off but not on anything important.

Syria doesn't ignore it.  Israel will respond by ensuring that Syria is in no position to interfere.  A bunch of damage to Syrian military units with very little to show for it.



Syria doesn't recognize Israel.  And it has been in a formal state of war with Israel since 1948.  As such, recognizing an action as an act war simply wouldn't accomplish anything.
Acts of war are only significant when they escalate relations in the direction of a war.  But acts of war (which is not the same as "war crimes") are expected during wars.

Well, users here complained/pointed to me that Syria and Israel formally have a ceasefire since '74, on their common border. The same is true e.g. about South and North Korea for instance. Both sides denounce violations of the ceasefire in that case, and even the UN takes a stance sometimes https://www.reuters.com/article/idUSKBN2320YY/ ; https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/1/26/n-korea-and-south-korea-violated-armistice-with-drone-flights-un

NK even threatened at times to 'cancel' the ceasefire, although it's not too clear what that would mean in practice. So, yeah, one can make diplomatic noise even during a war (and a ceasefire).

@thegodsfromengineering  cease fires happen in wars.  They don't automatically end just because acts of war happen.  Both the US and Iraq committed acts of war between "Operation Desert Storm" and "Operation Iraqi Freedom".  But the ceasefire held despite those acts of war.
